# Get href of wrapping anchor on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I need to be able to get the href (or somehow get the target url) of any `<a>` tag that is clicked even if it is wrapping another element.  For example, you could ordinarily do:

```
$("document").click(function (event) {
   url = event.target.href;
});
```

However, in this example, the `<a>` wraps an `<img>`, so the event target will not have the `href`.  Using `parentNode` is no good either, because there is also a span around the img in the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/z7ZYw/

I cannot change the selector either.

So is there any way to get the href in this circumstance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for jQuery's `closest` method:

```
$(e.target).closest('a');
```

Answer (score 3):

As a note, this can be done without jQuery aswell:

```
var href = (e.target.parentNode && e.target.parentNode.href) ? e.target.parentNode.href : e.target.href;
```

Comment: Yay! Thanks for the non-jQuery solution! (Not that I don't love jQuery.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind only on anchor tags:

```
$("a[href]").click(function () {
  console.log($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: I said that I cannot change the selector.

Comment: Ohh, that's sad. You can use @SLaks solution in this case.